# Слетел перевод ссылок на странице профиля

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, профиль-участника

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/current

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/current

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переводы выполнены и уже доступны на сайте:

> [image: основной]
>
> [image: мета]